# Using Generic T to Determine Compiler-Chosen Overload

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

I have the following code. The plan was for `GetSetting()` to call the appropriate version of `FromString()`, depending on the type of `T`.

```
public static T GetSetting<T>(PersistedSetting setting, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    return FromString(RegistrySettings.GetSetting(setting.ToString()) as string, defaultValue);
}

private static string FromString(string value, string defaultValue)
{
    return value ?? String.Empty;
}

private static int FromString(string value, int defaultValue)
{
    int i;
    return int.TryParse(value, out i) ? i : defaultValue;
}

private static decimal FromString(string value, decimal defaultValue)
{
    decimal d;
    return decimal.TryParse(value, out d) ? d : defaultValue;
}

private static bool FromString(string value, bool defaultValue)
{
    bool b;
    return bool.TryParse(value, out b) ? b : defaultValue;
}
```

However, on the line that calls `FromString()`, I get the compile error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'ArticleManager.PersistedSettings.FromString(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

The compiler assumes `FromString(string, string)`. Is there any way to have it use the appropriate overload for `T`?

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure but my best guess at what is happening is that overloading is determined at compile time, while `GetSetting()` doesn't know the type until run time. But, if that's the problem, how would one go about solving this particular problem?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know you aren't going to call GetSetting with DateTime, long, or Foo?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Well, that's a valid issue but, for now, it seems like a separate one. Right now, it assumes I will always call it with a string. Not sure I understand why that is happening, or the best way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's not always assuming you're calling it with a string, it's just selecting that one (from several) as a valid error message. The fact of the matter is your arguments are (string, T), and none of your overloads has that signature and the compiler is left to pull one overload to include in the message.

Comment: If you didn't have the (string, string) overload, the compiler would simply select another overload to include in the error message as it once again cannot find anything applicable.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Ok, I can see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload selection does happen at compile time. That's the issue.

You can make it happen at runtime using `dynamic`:

```
return FromString(RegistrySettings.GetSetting(setting.ToString()) as string, (dynamic)defaultValue);
```

Read more on MSDN: [Using Type `dynamic` (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Or you can make your method be non-generic method and have a set of overloads for `GetSetting`, e.g.

```
public static int GetSetting(PersistedSetting setting, int defaultValue = default(int))
{
    return FromString(RegistrySettings.GetSetting(setting.ToString()) as string, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: What is the effect of using `dynamic` like that? How does it get around the fact that overload selection happens at compile time?

Comment: Casting to `dynamic` makes the selection for that particular call happen at runtime. It will make it a bit slower, because the resolution has to be done before call can be made + if no suitable method is found at runtime you'll get an exception.

Comment: @JonathanWood, `dynamic` is basically a way to tell the compiler to  ignore certain aspects of the code *for now* and defer that type of analysis until the code is actually running. If there's anything illegal at that point, the program will blow up.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, that does work. But, again, does that mean your statement that "overload selection does happen at compile time" is only true sometimes?

Comment: `dynamic` is the only exception for that I know about.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Ok, thanks. Sorry to beat a dead horse, but shouldn't your statement "Overload selection does happen at compile time" be changed to something like "Overload selection normally happens at compile time"?